# Convert listBox.SelectedItem to PointF

Tags: c#-4.0, types, casting, lambda, type-conversion

I have an item in my listbox; 
I want to take it and convert it to PointF so that I can compare it with a list of pointF.

Example)
var selection = listBox3.SelectedItem ;  // like "{X=18,Y=48.10001}"

PointF p1 = (PointF) selection;

//now when that item has been selected and converted to float point, I want to search and find it in list called optFlowPoints to see if that points exists

PointF drawPointEst=optFlowPonits.Find(p=>p.Equals(selection));

So there are two problems:

1. how to convert selectedItem to PointF
2. how to write my lambda expression to find the match

Comment: I'm surprised `(PointF)selection` is not working for problem #1. Are you getting an InvalidCastException? Can you please post the code that fills the ListBox?

Comment: Yes sure,here is the code for filling: 
List<PointF> temp = new List<PointF>();   
listBox3.Items.AddRange(temp.ConvertAll(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: Yes,I get the invalidCastException saying " Specified cast is not valid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to convert selectedItem to PointF:

I think you could change the way you're filling the list. Have you tried `listBox3.Items.AddRange(temp.Cast<object>().ToArray());`? I think that should work, because ListBox calls ToString for you. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az.aspx) Then, your InvalidCastException should go away since your ListBox now contains PointF objects rather than strings.

How to write lambda expression to find the match:

```
PointF drawPointEst = optFlowPoints.Find(p => p == selection);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.op_equality.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work; dont know why

List<PointF> temp = new List<PointF>();
temp= optFlowPonits.Distinct().ToList();  
listBox3.Items.AddRange(temp.ConvertAll(p=>p.ToString()).ToArray());

////////
It gives following errors:
Error :The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)' has some invalid argument

Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.PointF[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'

Comment: Hmm, try this instead: `listBox3.Items.AddRange(temp.Cast<object>().ToArray());`. Hopefully that will make it use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
The error got fixed but just for my information can you please explain me where it was going wrong in listBox3.Items.AddRange(temp.ConvertAll(p => p.ToString()).ToArray());

Comment: The result of `temp.ConvertAll(p => p.ToString()).ToArray()` is an object of type string[]. The AddRange method can only accept either an object[] or an ObjectCollection. A string[] is neither of these, hence the compile error. But the Cast method casts each string to an object and returns an object[]. ... The reason you were getting an InvalidCastException earlier is because you were filling the list with strings and then trying to get one string out and cast it directly to a PointF. Can't do that. You could parse the string or do a RegEx to reassemble your own PointF, but you can't cast it.